# Laravel route redirect to wrong method

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, methods, routes

For the first time I have a problem with a route in laravel 5 (5.8.35).

I have a form that makes a post request to `/client/ban`

```html
<div class="text-center">
  <form action="/client/ban" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    Token:<br>
    <label>
      <input type="text" name="token">
    </label>
    <button type="submit" name="ban" value="1">Ban</button>
    <button type="submit" name="ban" value="0">Pardon</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

My routes are here, it should redirect my `/client/ban` request to the `action_ban_req` method.

```php
Route::post('/client/ban', 'HomeController@action_ban_req');
Route::post('/client/new', 'HomeController@action_new_req');
```

Here are my two methods, in the `HomeController.php` file, with, for debug purpose, have a very simple content (it contains other methods that works on theirs own routes);

```php
public function action_ban_req(Request $request)
{
    return "Test BAN";
}

public function action_new_req(Request $request)
{
    return "Test NEW";
}
```

However, every time I make a request, parameters are sent to `/client/ban` but it returns "Test NEW". I also tried with this route instead:

```php
Route::post('/client/ban', function () { return 'Test'; });
```

Even with that, there is no difference, I'm still stuck with a "Test NEW" response.

Did I miss something?

Edit: Nothing change when I swap order of routes, my others routes with `/client` prefix (that have other forms) works fine.

Comment: Do you have any other routes with `/client` prefix?

Comment: What happens when you switch the order of routes?

Comment: I tried and the order of routes doesn't seem to change result. Also, I have few others routes with `/client` prefix (and theirs form in html).

Comment: First, `composer dump-autoload`. Then, check if `php artisan route:list` show both paths.

Comment: It seems that I have old routes that doesn't exists anymore. I believe it's definitely cached somewhere. EDIT: OH THANKS DUDE, I solved it with a `php artisan route:cache`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jeff Harris, I found the problem.

As he said, I executed:

```sh
composer dump-autoload && php artisan route:list
```

I got a few old routes that shouldn't exist anymore, and some routes that were redirecting to the wrong controllers, then the problem was that laravel wasn't updating its route cache even if the `routes/web.php` file was edited, I don't know why.

I had to clear cache with the following:

```sh
php artisan route:cache
```

And after that `php artisan route:list` listed routes that redirected to the rights methods.

Comment: Heh route:cache gets me all the time too when I've got something old catching the route incorrectly.  Glad you got it solved.

Comment: Yes I assume it's a "noob" problem but (I might be lucky) I've been using laravel for 3 years and this is the first time I got this.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how far along you are in your project, but a failed route may be defaulting to `action_new_req`.  Or, there may be another route catching what your are sending to post.  Depending on how your site is set up, it looks like the problem may be that you are not sending a proper URL to the POST method.

Give this a try:

```
<form action="{{url('/client/ban')}}" method="post">
```

If the route wasn't getting the right base (e.g. `http://yoursite/client/ban`), this should solve it.

Comment: Same result: the url is good, it is the method redirection that's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Glastis.

I think you cannot send multiple actions with same form. Web.php takes the first match. 
But you can check into the controller the button hitted.

```
public function ban(Request $request){
switch ($request->input('action')) {
    case '0':
        // Case bam
        break;

    case '1':
        // Case Pardon
        break;
}}

<button type="submit" name="action" value="0">Ban</button>
<button type="submit" name="action" value="1">Pardon</button>
```

Comment: You can. I'm doing it in other views with other controllers and it's working fine.

Comment: and if you use action helper? <form method="post" action="{{ action('HomeController@action_ban_req') }}" accept-charset="UTF-8">

Comment: I found it, that was due to laravel that's not looking in `web.php` file but in its cached routes.But thanks :)